# Spirit X3 with boost::string_ref construction from semantic action

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit-x3

im confused with boost Spirit X3 and string_ref class. How to construct a string_ref object. The console prints somethink like this :

```
N5boost16basic_string_refIcSt11char_traitsIcEEE / N5boost14iterator_rangeIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPcNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEEEE
```

I dont know how to translate it to "normal type name" but it seems to me that i need to create the string_ref from a boost iterator range ?

```
 auto f = [](auto& ctx)
    { 
        auto val  = _val(ctx);
        auto attr = _attr(ctx);

        std::cout << typeid(val).name() << " / " << typeid(attr).name() << "\n";
        // _val(ctx) = boost::string_ref( attr.c_str(), 1 ); //phx::construct<boost::string_ref>( _where(ctx).begin(), _attr(ctx).size() );
     };
```

And the rule is :

```
  auto const quote  = rule<struct quote, Type>{"quote"} 
                    =    lit('"')
                     >> raw[*~char_('"')][ f ]
                     >> lit('"');
```

Comment: ["normal type name"](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07afc74fd304649d).

Comment: Be careful creating a `string_ref` from an `iterator_range`. A `string_ref` requires the characters to be contiguous, while `iterator_range` does not.  You have to assure that yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the comment from `cv_and_he` I'm using the following lambda as semantic action

```
auto f = [](auto& ctx)
{ 
    auto& attr = _attr(ctx);
    _val(ctx) = boost::string_ref( &attr[0], attr.size() );
};
```

Comment: Not too sure that makes sense. After all now  you have a dangling ref to a temporary string or vector, in 99% of the cases.